# How to make certain event happen on a specific item when mapping through an array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am mapping through an array and displaying its data. I have edit button to modify that data. When I click edit button, dropdown shows and I am able to edit as shown in screenshot I shared. [Open this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5gTc.png)

Problem is all of edit buttons work even when I click any one, I want only clicked edit button to work rather than all. How can I achieve this functionality?

This is my code:

`const [show, setShow] = useState(false);`

`const handleShow = () => { setShow(!show); };`

```
 <p onClick={handleShow}>
              Edit
              {show === true ? (
                <IoIosArrowUp style={{ color: "#F1BB0F" }} />
              ) : (
                <IoIosArrowDown style={{ color: "#F1BB0F" }} />
              )}
            </p>

              {show && (
            <div>
              <p>
                Unlocks: {lockParams[index]?.endDateString}
              </p>
              <p>
                Unlocker : <span>{lockParams[index]?.unlocker}</span>
              </p>
            </div>
          )}
```

Comment: What are you iterating over? Can you show the outer `.map` in the JSX?

Comment: Its coming from backend. @CertainPerformance

Comment: Can you show that full rendering code? That'll be the key to knowing how to fix the problem

Comment: Check here: https://codeshare.io/bv88lM

Comment: Please post the code in the question itself, so that the question can be useful to future readers even if the link dies, per SO rules

Answer (score 0):

If you have N different buttons, and you want the view to be different depending on which of those buttons are toggled on or off, you should have state corresponding to those N buttons. An array of booleans would make sense here. That way, if, say, the 4th button is toggled, you can update the 4th element in the state array, and then when the component renders, while iterating over the 4th index, it can look at that 4th boolean to see what should be shown there.

You haven't shown the necessary code in the question, but, for example, if you have:

```
someArray.map((item) => (
  // some JSX
  <p onClick={handleShow}>
    // etc
```

Then you need to initialize a state array containing the same number of elements as `someArray`, like this:

```
const [shows, setShows] = useState(() => someArray.map(() => false));
const handleShow = (i) => setShows((show, j) => j === i ? !show : show);
```

And then use index when rendering:

```
someArray.map((item, i) => (
    // some JSX
    <p onClick={() => handleShow(i)}>
        Edit
        {shows[i] ? (
            <IoIosArrowUp style={{ color: "#F1BB0F" }} />
        ) : (
            <IoIosArrowDown style={{ color: "#F1BB0F" }} />
        )}
    </p>

    {shows[i] && (
        <div>
            <p>
                Unlocks: {lockParams[index]?.endDateString}
```